# To Deserialize json files to object with different properties name

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have a json files list ,each json format file  has items 'cpu' ,'mem','disk',and each item has different properties.
for example:
cpu has properties like 'Cpustatus','Brand Name','Size' and so on.

I have done the job to deserialize the json file,with a class Root to store the object

[image]

And the code below worked well:

```
        static void PrintParseJsonstr2Info(string jsonstr,string filename="not set")
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonstr)))
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer deseralizer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Root));
            Root rt = (Root)deseralizer.ReadObject(ms);
            var cpulist = rt.Cpu;
            Console.WriteLine($"file:{filename},cpulist.Count()={cpulist?.Count}");
            foreach (var cpuitem in cpulist)
            {
                foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo info in cpuitem.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(info.Name + ":" + cpuitem.GetType().GetProperty(info.Name.ToString()).GetValue(cpuitem, null));
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"-------------------{filename}-CPU OVER------------------------------------");
            }
            var disklist = rt.Disk;
            Console.WriteLine($"file:{filename},disklist.Count()={disklist?.Count}");
            foreach (DiskItem diskitem in disklist)
            {
                foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo info in diskitem.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(info.Name + ":" + diskitem.GetType().GetProperty(info.Name.ToString()).GetValue(diskitem, null));
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"-------------------{filename}-DISK OVER--------------------------------");
            }

            var memlist = rt.Mem;
            Console.WriteLine($"file:{filename},memlist.Count()={memlist?.Count}");
            foreach (MemItem memitem in memlist)
            {
                foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo info in memitem.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(info.Name + ":" + memitem.GetType().GetProperty(info.Name.ToString()).GetValue(memitem, null));
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"------------------{filename}-Mem OVER--------------------------------");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"------------------------{filename} OVER------------------------");
  
    }
```

but my company code criterion has a rule that the name of properties must be upper case,
which means I should change the class Root:

```
public List<CpuItem> **Cpu**{get;set;}
```

that makes that the names is mismatched with the one in the json format file,which caused the code run errorly.

The question is how can I make the deserialization run well with the mismatched properties names

Answer (score -2):

You can use DataContract for this.

```
[DataContract]
public class Root
{
  [DataMember(Name = "cpu")]
  public List<CpuItem> Cpu { get; set; }
  [DataMember(Name = "disk")]
  public List<DiskItem> Disk { get; set; }
  [DataMember(Name = "mem")]
  public List<MemItem> Mem { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please paste code as text and format as code using Markdown instead of embedding code as an image. Can you edit your answer to include that?